# Unable to install snowflake-sqlalchemy because of pyarrow and cmake

Tags: python, cmake, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to install Snowflake SQLAlchemy with the command `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy` but it fails to install because pyarrow wheels cannot be built (because cmake cannot be found).

```
        error: command 'cmake' failed: No such file or directory
        [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Failed to build pyarrow
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried installing cmake with `pip install cmake` and installing pyarrow with `pip install pyarrow` and neither have worked. I already installed the python connector with `pip install snowflake-connector-python`. I am using Python 3.11.1 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like pyarrow is not compatible (even though the website says it is) with  Python 3.11. Downgrading to Python 3.9 worked.